# How i can find realization of some function in Perl source?

Tags: perl

For example, i want to find source code for 'print' or 'foreach' operators.
I have downloaded Perl source and want to see 'real' code for this operators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl compiles the source code to a graph called the *Opcode Tree*. At the same time, this data structure represents the syntax and control flow of your program. To understand opcodes, you may want to start with the [*Illustrated Perl Guts (illguts)*](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.42/index-14.html).

To find out to what Ops your program was compiled, you call it like so:

- `perl -MO=Concise script.pl` – to get the opcodes in their syntax tree
- `perl -MO=Concise,-exec script.pl` – the `-exec` option orders the ops in their execution order instead. Sometimes, this is less confusing.
- `perl -MO=Concise,foo script.pl` – dump the ops of the `foo` subroutine.

A typical opcode looks like:

```
4 <$> const[PV "007B"] s/FOLD ->5
^  ^  ^                ^      ^
|  |  |                |      The next op in execution order
|  |  |                Flags for this op, documented e.g. in illguts. "s" is
|  |  |                scalar context. After the slash, op-specific stuff
|  |  The actual name of the op, may list further arguments
|  The optype ($: unop, 2: binop, @:listop) – not really useful
The op number
```

Ops are declared like `PP(pp_const)`. To search for that declaration, use the [`ack` tool](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Ack), which is an intelligent, recursive `grep` with Perl regexes. To search all C files and headers in the top direcory of the source, we do:

```
$ ack 'pp_const' *.c *.h
```

Output (here without color):

```
op.c
29: * points to the pp_const() function and to an SV containing the constant
30: * value. When pp_const() is executed, its job is to push that SV onto the

pp_hot.c
40:PP(pp_const)

opcode.h
944:    Perl_pp_const,

pp_proto.h
43:PERL_CALLCONV OP *Perl_pp_const(pTHX);
```

So it's declared in `pp_hot.c`, line 40. I tend to do `vim pp_hot.c +40` to go there. Then we see the definition:

```
PP(pp_const)
{
    dVAR;
    dSP;
    XPUSHs(cSVOP_sv);
    RETURN;
}
```

To understand this, you should get a minimal knowledge of the [Perl API](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html), and maybe write a bit of XS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
So, if i have same output this means, that we have same code for two operators?  
like:  
    bash-4.1$ perl -MO=Concise -e "for (1,2,3) {};"  
    bash-4.1$ perl -MO=Concise -e "foreach(1,2,3) {};"

Comment: @helgi Yes. The opcodes are a direct representation of your program. If two programs have the same opcodes, they behave exactly the same. (In your case, it is documented somewhere that the `for` and `foreach` keywords are the same. However, that difference is removed by the parser before the opcodes are created.)